# Iterating objects or arrays inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The JSON I'm passing into my view has objects and arrays inside of it. Example:

```
{ name: "test", projects: [ { name: "project1", tasks: "task1" } ] }
```

Using ng-repeat, I can say `(key, value) in items` and am given what you'd expect, each key and the stringified version of the object or array.

Is there a 'best practice' for iterating over the objects and arrays inside an ng-repeat?

Comment: It depends on how are you going to display the data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just following up with an answer, as I was able to figure this out. It was simpler than I realized. Just used another ng-repeat for items that were arrays.

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in items">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th class="span3">name</th>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="span3">accounts</th>
        <td>
            <ul ng-repeat="account in item.accounts">
                <li>username: {{ account.username }}</li>
                <li>password: {{ account.password }}</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```